# Node app create production build for live web site - static files (no node running on webhost)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ftp

I have a question which sounds maybe trivial, but I feel like I life behind the moon.

In those default React Apps, which are initialised by

```
npm install -g create-react-app 
create-react-app my app
```

I build whatever with this app and in the end of the day, I put in

```
npm run build
```

and it builds static files that I can upload via ftp to my existing Webspace with my domain live in the internet. No Haruko, no AWS, no installing node anywhere.

**Now my question, how can I do the same with a random node.js ?**

I find a gazillion tutorials how to build apps on an server on localhost and even many on how to install node in some webspace.

But how do I generate those 'static files' that I just upload via FTP and dones? Am I the only one who wants to do it that way?

If so, what is wrong with that thinking?

Comment: It depends upon what you're trying to build.  If you have a web site that needs NO server-side logic of any kind and all Javascript runs in your web pages (in the browser), then sure you can create a web site based purely on static files.  But, this has nothing to do with node.js at all because there would be no node.js executing anywhere.  So, its not very clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: I got it I think! Of course what I did build before was able to be served with no server side logic.

Fiddeled now with node and installed it on my webserver. Have not yet completely understanding of all but it is running.

Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Michael I am looking for the same thing, actually I want to upload a web app having react.js on front end and node.js at backend to get the data from mysql database and show to user? 

Did you achieve the same on shared hosting or you did it on VPS ?

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan I was puzzling this for a while.

I have managed to have my Node application running on my server since my (shared) hosting provider fortunately enables this by default. 

I however went back to create static files from my application. I learned a lot about webpack to create a production build. Did take a while to learn, but it saves me the trouble of having Node running on the server.

My app was btw a Wordpress Blog. First I wanted to create my own blog with React and MongoDB. But I found it more useful to keep Wordpress and work with its API and React as front-end app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [web-boost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-boost) static site generator with page-speed optimizations.

You have to explicitly show all the routes you are going to convert from dynamic application into static ones like this:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/": {
      "view": "index.twig",
      "vars": {
        "title": "Home page",
        "greeting": "Hello world!"
      },
      "assets": {
        "js/index.min.js": [
          "js/index.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    "/user": {
      "view": "user.twig",
      "vars": {
        "title": "User's page",
        "greeting": "Hi John Doe!"
      },
      "assets": {
        "css/user.min.css": [
          "styles/bootstrap.min.css",
          "styles/user.scss"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then run compile command and deploy your static pages into AWS.S3 bucket for example.